# How to monitor application running in a Kubernetes cluster from a remote Promethues server

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus

My goal is to monitor application running in a Kubernetes cluster from a remote Prometheus server. Based on: https://medium.com/@amjadhussain3751/monitor-remote-kubernetes-cluster-using-prometheus-a3781b041745

I did:

1. Create a service account which has permissions to read and watch the pods.
2. Generate token from the service account.

I put the token in the prometheus.yaml as describe in the post:

```
-------
  - job_name: kubernetes-service-endpoints
    scrape_interval: 15s
    scrape_timeout: 10s
    metrics_path: /metrics
    scheme: http
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - api_server: http://kk-kk-0-73.mycompany.com:6443
      role: endpoints
      tls_config:
        insecure_skip_verify: true
      bearer_token: "ZXlKaGJHY2lP ......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"
      namespaces:
        names: []
    bearer_token: "ZXlKaGJHY2l ..... 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"
    relabel_configs:

----
```

When I start my prometheus, I got errors as the followings

```
---
level=error ts=2021-04-29T20:51:27.255Z caller=klog.go:104 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Errorf msg="Unexpected error when reading response body: read tcp pm.pm.pm.15:51652->kk.kk.0.73:6443: read: connection reset by peer"
level=error ts=2021-04-29T20:51:27.256Z caller=klog.go:96 component=k8s_client_runtime func=ErrorDepth msg="pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.20.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1.Pod: failed to list *v1.Pod: unexpected error when reading response body. Please retry. Original error: read tcp pm.pm.pm.15:51652->kk.kk.0.73:6443: read: connection reset by peer"
level=debug ts=2021-04-29T20:51:27.445Z caller=klog.go:55 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Verbose.Infof msg="Listing and watching *v1.Endpoints from pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.20.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167"
level=debug ts=2021-04-29T20:51:27.495Z caller=klog.go:72 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Infof msg="GET http://kk.kk.0-73.mycommany.com:6443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0 400 Bad Request in 49 milliseconds"
level=error ts=2021-04-29T20:51:27.495Z caller=klog.go:104 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Errorf msg="Unexpected error when reading response body: read tcp pm.pm.pm.15:51654->kk.kk.0.73:6443: read: connection reset by peer"
level=error ts=2021-04-29T20:51:27.495Z caller=klog.go:96 component=k8s_client_runtime func=ErrorDepth msg="pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.20.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1.Endpoints: failed to list *v1.Endpoints: unexpected error when reading response body. Please retry. Original error: read tcp pm.pm.pm.15:51654->kk.kk.0.73:6443: read: connection reset by peer"

---
```

Note: the following represents the ip address of my prometheus server and k8s master node ip

```
prometheus  server ip:          pm.pm.pm.15
K8s cluster master node ip:     kk.kk.0.73
```

btw telnet from pm.pm.pm.15 to kk.kk.0.73:6443 is good.

Did I set the parameters correctly? How to troubleshoot? Any suggestions appreciated.

-dsun

some contents of my object config yaml

```
--- service_account.yaml  ---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: prom-mon-acct
  namespace: monitoring
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: prometheus-mon-acct-rb
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: prometheus
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: prom-mon-acct
  namespace: monitoring

----cluster_role.yaml ---
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: prometheus
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - nodes
  - nodes/proxy
  - services
  - endpoints
  - pods
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
- nonResourceURLs: ["/metrics"]
  verbs: ["get"]
---
```

[update 1]

last few line from: kubectl logs kube-apiserver-kk-kk-0-73.mycomoany.com -n kube-system

```
....

I0429 22:30:36.256704       1 clientconn.go:948] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
I0429 22:31:18.638120       1 client.go:360] parsed scheme: "passthrough"
I0429 22:31:18.638164       1 passthrough.go:48] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
I0429 22:31:18.638175       1 clientconn.go:948] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
I0429 22:31:56.333614       1 client.go:360] parsed scheme: "passthrough"
I0429 22:31:56.333660       1 passthrough.go:48] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
I0429 22:31:56.333671       1 clientconn.go:948] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
I0429 22:32:38.907517       1 client.go:360] parsed scheme: "passthrough"
I0429 22:32:38.907560       1 passthrough.go:48] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
I0429 22:32:38.907570       1 clientconn.go:948] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
I0429 22:33:14.696739       1 client.go:360] parsed scheme: "passthrough"
I0429 22:33:14.696781       1 passthrough.go:48] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
I0429 22:33:14.696792       1 clientconn.go:948] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
```

[update 2]
test with: # curl -X GET $YOUR_API_SERVER/api --header "Authorization: Bearer $YOUR_TOKEN" and using https instead of http

```
NAMESPACE         NAME                              TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default           default-token-j2bvm               kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      4d14h    ---> token from this account is working with curl api server, but don't have list pod privs
monitoring        prom-mon-acct-token-4fchr         kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      19h      --->  token from this service account not working with curl api server

I know prom-mon-acct service account has list pod privs, need to figure out how to make it able to talk to API.
```

Comment: Hi Check the logs of API Server, Why its reseting the connections ?

Comment: see last few lines of the logs from API server in [update 1]

Comment: Welcome to the community @dsun!
Based on the GET request and 400 response and prometheus.yaml, you should try changing `scheme` from `http` to `https` and `api_server` to `https://kk-kk-0-73.mycompany.com:6443` because API server uses https traffic.
Also you can test your token with the following command:
`curl -X GET $YOUR_API_SERVER/api --header "Authorization: Bearer $YOUR_TOKEN" --insecure` (reference is [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#without-kubectl-proxy))

Comment: @moonkotte thanks for your help. I think i am closer to the solution. see [update 2]

Comment: I am wondering if the service account I created "prom-mon-acct" need to bind to some kind of "ClusterRole" so its token can be used to connect to API server?

Comment: `ClusterRoleBinding` does exactly what you said, matches `CusterRole` with your `ServiceAccount`. I was able to reproduce connection to API with bearer token using your yamls. So I can guess that in this command `TOKEN=$(kubectl get secrets -n monitoring -o jsonpath="{.items[?(@.metadata.annotations['kubernetes\.io/service-account\.name']=='prom-mon-acct')].data.token}"|base64 --decode)` you might miss a `-n monitoring`. You can easily check it right after this command by `echo $TOKEN`

Comment: @mookotte  I am able to connect to API with the bearer token after making sure " -n monitoring"  is there.  Now it seems my remote prom server can discover the application endpoint target in the k8s cluster, however I got error like the following "
level=debug ts=2021-05-24T17:10:42.112Z caller=scrape.go:1127 component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=kubernetes-service-endpoints target=http://10.244.0.4:8081/metrics msg="Scrape failed" err="Get \"http://10.244.0.4:8081/metrics\": context deadline exceeded"
Inside the k8s node:  curl http://10.244.0.4:8081/metrics has no issue

Comment: do you have any proxy for kube api server?